# Populating Cached Data

Tags: javascript

Consider the following caching on query function in javascript

```
channelCache={};
async getChannelType(channel: string): Promise<string> {
    if (!this.channelCache.hasOwnProperty(channel)) {
         channelCache[channel] = await this._deviceService.GetChannelSetting(channel);
     }
     return channelCache[channel];
}
```

This works well however there is a scenario in my code where this is called 100 times one after another.  The issue is that all 100 times gets past the if statement and starts querying the service.  What I'd like if some sort of mutex mechanism around the if statement that will only allow 1 query to run at a time.

I've tried prex semaphore but it looks like this  does not work in IE 11. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any kind of semaphores or locking.

Instead, you should cache your async promise instead of the final value:

```
getChannelType(channel: string): Promise<string> {
    if (!this.channelCache.hasOwnProperty(channel)) {
         channelCache[channel] = this._deviceService.GetChannelSetting(channel);
     }
     return channelCache[channel];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  You forced me to rethink my caching mechanism and it ended up working great.